# Call common function in different component HTML on onchange event from any common service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Hello I am using angular 11 ..
I have three components suppose C1, C2 and C3, components do not have parent child relationship . Now all components have one common method
suppose F1 . Currently this F1 is declared in all components .ts file and called in component HTML file
in change event like this

HTML

```
(change)="F1($event.target.value,i,opt.value)"
```

.ts

```
 F1(value, index, optVal) {
    // code goes here 
  }
```

How Can I declare this method F1 only once in service and used it in components HTML file.
I know how to use in .ts file but how can I call F1 on change event from common service .

Answer (score 0):

you declare F1 in your controller, then you call your injected commonservice function from the controller's F1 `F1(a:string, b:number, c:$event) => this.commonService.F1(a,b,c);`

Answer (score 0):

HTML for C1, C2, C3

```
(change)="F1($event.target.value,i,opt.value)"
```

.ts for C1, C2, C3

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

F1(value, index, optVal) {
  this.myService.F1(value, index, optVal);
}
```

my-service.ts

```
F1(value, index, optVal) {
  // do stuff here
}
```

To generate service use CLI command:

```
ng g s path/my-service
```

EDIT:

To bypass using C1, C2, C3 .ts file - in each components .ts file just do this:

```
constructor(public myService: MyService) {}
```

here the service is public - In the HTML you can now directly access myService.F1 - no need to declare F1 in any components - although this is not an approach I like